# How to prevent the user to go back on login page by clicking on back button of browser in jsp?

Tags: java, jsp, model-view-controller

I am building a web application in jsp through MVC approach!
In this app once a user logged in through Login.jsp page and then he is redirected to AdminPanel.jsp but if he click the back button he again can view the Login.jsp page. I want that once a user logged in and click the back button or manually enter the AdminPanel.jsp url in the browser he must be redirected to AdminPanel.jsp page! I have done the following with the Login page. It works good after the user manually enter the url after logging in e.g
Localhost:8080/ERT/Login.jsp
It redirects to AdminPanel.jsp if logged in already. But if we press back button it dont redirect to AdminPanel.jsp but go back to Login.jsp..

```
<body>
<% 
 if(session.getAttribute("id")!=null)
{

   response.sendRedirect("AdminPanel.jsp");
}
%>

<%!String errormsg; %>
<form action = "AdminLogin" method = "post">

    Username : <input type = "text" name = "username"/ ><br />
    Password : <input type = "password" name = "password"/><br />
    <input type = "submit" value = "submit" />

</form>
</body>
```

Comment: When you press back, it doesn't always request to the server again.  The user is seeing a cached page.  Either don't worry about it, or set no-cache headers on the page to prevent the browser from caching it.